# why I take this plot with matplotlib.pyplot when add date too x axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, ta-lib

First data frame:

```
          date      time      open      high       low     close          volume        avg
0   2021-05-23  00:00:00  37458.51  38270.64  31111.01  34655.25   217136.046593        NaN
1   2021-05-24  00:00:00  34681.44  39920.00  34031.00  38796.29   161630.893971        NaN
2   2021-05-25  00:00:00  38810.99  39791.77  36419.62  38324.72   111996.228404        NaN
3   2021-05-26  00:00:00  38324.72  40841.00  37800.44  39241.91   104780.773396        NaN
4   2021-05-27  00:00:00  39241.92  40411.14  37134.27  38529.98    86547.158794        NaN
5   2021-05-28  00:00:00  38529.99  38877.83  34684.00  35663.49   135377.629720        NaN
6   2021-05-29  00:00:00  35661.79  37338.58  33632.76  34605.15   112663.092689        NaN
7   2021-05-30  00:00:00  34605.15  36488.00  33379.00  35641.27    73535.386967        NaN
8   2021-05-31  00:00:00  35641.26  37499.00  34153.84  37253.81    94160.735289        NaN
9   2021-01-06  00:00:00  37253.82  37894.81  35666.00  36693.09    81234.663770        NaN
10  2021-02-06  00:00:00  36694.85  38225.00  35920.00  37568.68    67587.372495        NaN
11  2021-03-06  00:00:00  37568.68  39476.00  37170.00  39246.79    75889.106011        NaN
12  2021-04-06  00:00:00  39246.78  39289.07  35555.15  36829.00    91317.799245        NaN
13  2021-05-06  00:00:00  36829.15  37925.00  34800.00  35513.20    70459.621490        NaN
14  2021-06-06  00:00:00  35516.07  36480.00  35222.00  35796.31    47650.206637        NaN
15  2021-07-06  00:00:00  35796.31  36900.00  33300.00  33552.79    77574.952573        NaN
16  2021-08-06  00:00:00  33556.96  34068.01  31000.00  33380.81   123251.189037        NaN
17  2021-09-06  00:00:00  33380.80  37534.79  32396.82  37388.05   136607.597517        NaN
18  2021-10-06  00:00:00  37388.05  38491.00  35782.00  36675.72   109527.284943        NaN
19  2021-11-06  00:00:00  36677.83  37680.40  35936.77  37331.98    78466.005300        NaN
20  2021-12-06  00:00:00  37331.98  37463.63  34600.36  35546.11    87717.549990        NaN
21  2021-06-13  00:00:00  35546.12  39380.00  34757.00  39020.57    86921.025555        NaN
22  2021-06-14  00:00:00  39020.56  41064.05  38730.00  40516.29   108522.391949        NaN
23  2021-06-15  00:00:00  40516.28  41330.00  39506.40  40144.04    80679.622838        NaN
24  2021-06-16  00:00:00  40143.80  40527.14  38116.01  38349.01    87771.976937        NaN
25  2021-06-17  00:00:00  38349.00  39559.88  37365.00  38092.97    79541.307119        NaN
26  2021-06-18  00:00:00  38092.97  38202.84  35129.29  35819.84    95228.042935        NaN
27  2021-06-19  00:00:00  35820.48  36457.00  34803.52  35483.72    68712.449461        NaN
28  2021-06-20  00:00:00  35483.72  36137.72  33336.00  35600.16    89878.170850        NaN
29  2021-06-21  00:00:00  35600.17  35750.00  31251.23  31608.93   168778.873159        NaN
30  2021-06-22  00:00:00  31614.12  33298.78  28805.00  32509.56   204208.179762        NaN
31  2021-06-23  00:00:00  32509.56  34881.00  31683.00  33678.07   126966.100563        NaN
32  2021-06-24  00:00:00  33675.07  35298.00  32286.57  34663.09    86625.804260        NaN
33  2021-06-25  00:00:00  34663.08  35500.00  31275.00  31584.45   116061.130356        NaN
34  2021-06-26  00:00:00  31576.09  32730.00  30151.00  32283.65   107820.375287        NaN
35  2021-06-27  00:00:00  32283.65  34749.00  31973.45  34700.34    96613.244211        NaN
36  2021-06-28  00:00:00  34702.49  35297.71  33862.72  34494.89    82222.267819        NaN
37  2021-06-29  00:00:00  34494.89  36600.00  34225.43  35911.73    90788.796220        NaN
38  2021-06-30  00:00:00  35911.72  36100.00  34017.55  35045.00    77152.197634        NaN
39  2021-01-07  00:00:00  35045.00  35057.57  32711.00  33504.69    71708.266112  15.362372
40  2021-02-07  00:00:00  33502.33  33977.04  32699.00  33786.55    56172.181378  15.386331
41  2021-03-07  00:00:00  33786.54  34945.61  33316.73  34669.13    43044.578641  15.154877
42  2021-04-07  00:00:00  34669.12  35967.85  34357.15  35286.51    43703.475789  14.677524
43  2021-05-07  00:00:00  35288.13  35293.78  33125.55  33690.14    64123.874245  14.486827
44  2021-06-07  00:00:00  33690.15  35118.88  33532.00  34220.01    58210.596349  14.305665
45  2021-07-07  00:00:00  34220.02  35059.09  33777.77  33862.12    53807.521675  14.133561
46  2021-08-07  00:00:00  33862.11  33929.64  32077.00  32875.71    70136.480320  14.336865
47  2021-09-07  00:00:00  32875.71  34100.00  32261.07  33815.81    47153.939899  14.479159
48  2021-10-07  00:00:00  33815.81  34262.00  33004.78  33502.87    34761.175468  14.564313
49  2021-11-07  00:00:00  33502.87  34666.00  33306.47  34258.99    31572.647448  14.517866
50  2021-12-07  00:00:00  34259.00  34678.43  32658.34  33086.63    48181.403762  14.627892
51  2021-07-13  00:00:00  33086.94  33340.00  32202.25  32729.77    41126.361008  14.839689
52  2021-07-14  00:00:00  32729.12  33114.03  31550.00  32820.02    46777.823484  15.192346
53  2021-07-15  00:00:00  32820.03  33185.25  31133.00  31880.00    51639.576353  15.623083
54  2021-07-16  00:00:00  31874.49  32249.18  31020.00  31383.87    48499.864154  16.058731
55  2021-07-17  00:00:00  31383.86  31955.92  31164.31  31520.07    34012.242132  16.472596
56  2021-07-18  00:00:00  31520.07  32435.00  31108.97  31778.56    35923.716186  16.669426
57  2021-07-19  00:00:00  31778.57  31899.00  30407.44  30839.65    47340.468499  17.041150
58  2021-07-20  00:00:00  30839.65  31063.07  29278.00  29790.35    61034.049017  17.671053
59  2021-07-21  00:00:00  29790.34  32858.00  29482.61  32144.51    82796.265128  17.564616
60  2021-07-22  00:00:00  32144.51  32591.35  31708.00  32287.83    46148.092433  17.463500
61  2021-07-23  00:00:00  32287.58  33650.00  31924.32  33634.09    50112.863626  16.984139
62  2021-07-24  00:00:00  33634.10  34500.00  33401.14  34258.14    47977.550138  16.242346
63  2021-07-25  00:00:00  34261.51  35398.00  33851.12  35381.02    47852.928313  15.607586
64  2021-07-26  00:00:00  35381.02  40550.00  35205.78  37237.60   152452.512724  16.219395
65  2021-07-27  00:00:00  37241.33  39542.61  36383.00  39457.87    88397.267015  16.800613
66  2021-07-28  00:00:00  39456.61  40900.00  38772.00  40019.56   101344.528441  17.599907
67  2021-07-29  00:00:00  40019.57  40640.00  39200.00  40016.48    53998.439283  18.359237
68  2021-07-30  00:00:00  40018.49  42316.71  38313.23  42206.37    73602.784805  19.368676
69  2021-07-31  00:00:00  42206.36  42448.00  41000.15  41461.83    44849.791012  20.349200
70  2021-01-08  00:00:00  41461.84  42599.00  39422.01  39845.44    53953.186326  20.714136
71  2021-02-08  00:00:00  39850.27  40480.01  38690.00  39147.82    50837.351954  20.816480
72  2021-03-08  00:00:00  39146.86  39780.00  37642.03  38207.05    57117.435853  20.578895
73  2021-04-08  00:00:00  38207.04  39969.66  37508.56  39723.18    52329.352430  20.396351
74  2021-05-08  00:00:00  39723.17  41350.00  37332.70  40862.46    84343.755621  20.526294
75  2021-06-08  00:00:00  40862.46  43392.43  39853.86  42836.87    75753.941347  21.042989
76  2021-07-08  00:00:00  42836.87  44700.00  42446.41  44572.54    73396.740808  21.756471
77  2021-08-08  00:00:00  44572.54  45310.00  43261.00  43794.37    69329.092698  22.533424
78  2021-09-08  00:00:00  43794.36  46454.15  42779.00  46253.40    74587.884845  23.450453
79  2021-10-08  00:00:00  46248.87  46700.00  44589.46  45584.99    53814.643421  24.359303
80  2021-11-08  00:00:00  45585.00  46743.47  45341.14  45511.00    52734.901977  25.229618
81  2021-12-08  00:00:00  45510.67  46218.12  43770.00  44399.00    55266.108781  25.471002
82  2021-08-13  00:00:00  44400.06  47886.00  44217.39  47800.00    48239.370431  25.995794
83  2021-08-14  00:00:00  47799.99  48144.00  45971.03  47068.51    46114.359022  26.537795
84  2021-08-15  00:00:00  47068.50  47372.27  45500.00  46973.82    42110.711334  26.878796
85  2021-08-16  00:00:00  46973.82  48053.83  45660.00  45901.29    52480.574014  27.326937
86  2021-08-17  00:00:00  45901.30  47160.00  44376.00  44695.95    57039.341629  27.285215
87  2021-08-18  00:00:00  44695.95  46000.00  44203.28  44705.29    54099.415985  27.184539
88  2021-08-19  00:00:00  44699.37  47033.00  43927.70  46760.62    53411.753920  27.302916
89  2021-08-20  00:00:00  46760.62  49382.99  46622.99  49322.47    56850.352228  27.840242
90  2021-08-21  00:00:00  49322.47  49757.04  48222.00  48821.87    46745.136584  28.412062
91  2021-08-22  00:00:00  48821.88  49500.00  48050.00  49239.22    37007.887795  28.889153
92  2021-08-23  00:00:00  49239.22  50500.00  49029.00  49488.85    52462.541954  29.512800
93  2021-08-24  00:00:00  49488.85  49860.00  47600.00  47674.01    51014.594748  29.565824
94  2021-08-25  00:00:00  47674.01  49264.30  47126.28  48973.32    44655.830342  29.446836
95  2021-08-26  00:00:00  48973.32  49352.84  46250.00  46843.87    49371.277774  29.028026
96  2021-08-27  00:00:00  46843.86  49149.93  46348.00  49069.90    42068.104965  28.630156
97  2021-08-28  00:00:00  49069.90  49299.00  48346.88  48895.35    26681.063786  28.287626
98  2021-08-29  00:00:00  48895.35  49632.27  47762.54  48767.83    32652.283473  27.744622
99  2021-08-30  00:00:00  48767.84  48888.61  46853.00  46982.91    40288.350830  26.903998
100 2021-08-31  00:00:00  46982.91  48246.11  46700.00  47100.89    48645.527370  26.051605
101 2021-01-09  00:00:00  47100.89  49156.00  46512.00  48810.52    49904.655280  25.499838
102 2021-02-09  00:00:00  48810.51  50450.13  48584.06  49246.64    54410.770538  25.311075
103 2021-03-09  00:00:00  49246.63  51000.00  48316.84  49999.14    59025.644157  25.265214
104 2021-04-09  00:00:00  49998.00  50535.69  49370.00  49915.64    34664.659590  25.221647
105 2021-05-09  00:00:00  49917.54  51900.00  49450.00  51756.88    40544.835873  25.504286
106 2021-06-09  00:00:00  51756.88  52780.00  50969.33  52663.90    49249.667081  25.962876
107 2021-07-09  00:00:00  52666.20  52920.00  42843.05  46863.73   123048.802719  25.276717
108 2021-08-09  00:00:00  46868.57  47340.99  44412.02  46048.31    65069.315200  24.624866
109 2021-09-09  00:00:00  46048.31  47399.97  45513.08  46395.14    50651.660020  23.989928
110 2021-10-09  00:00:00  46395.14  47033.00  44132.29  44850.91    49048.266180  23.670387
111 2021-11-09  00:00:00  44842.20  45987.93  44722.22  45173.69    30440.408100  23.366822
112 2021-12-09  00:00:00  45173.68  46460.00  44742.06  46025.24    32094.280520  22.938381
113 2021-09-13  00:00:00  46025.23  46880.00  43370.00  44940.73    65429.150560  22.820722
114 2021-09-14  00:00:00  44940.72  47250.00  44594.44  47111.52    44855.850990  22.594896
115 2021-09-15  00:00:00  47103.28  48500.00  46682.32  48121.41    43204.711740  22.007531
116 2021-09-16  00:00:00  48121.40  48557.00  47021.10  47737.82    40725.088950  21.432816
117 2021-09-17  00:00:00  47737.81  48150.00  46699.56  47299.98    34461.927760  20.965565
118 2021-09-18  00:00:00  47299.98  48843.20  47035.56  48292.74    30906.470380  20.306487
119 2021-09-19  00:00:00  48292.75  48372.83  46829.18  47241.75    29847.243490  19.735184
120 2021-09-20  00:00:00  47241.75  47347.25  42500.00  43015.62    78003.524443  20.139851
121 2021-09-21  00:00:00  43016.64  43639.00  39600.00  40734.38    84534.080485  20.985744
122 2021-09-22  00:00:00  40734.09  44000.55  40565.39  43543.61    58349.055420  21.676235
123 2021-09-23  00:00:00  43546.37  44978.00  43069.09  44865.26    48699.576550  22.029837
124 2021-09-24  00:00:00  44865.26  45200.00  40675.00  42810.57    84113.426292  22.735109
125 2021-09-25  00:00:00  42810.58  42966.84  41646.28  42670.64    33594.571890  23.405118
126 2021-09-26  00:00:00  42670.63  43950.00  40750.00  43160.90    49879.997650  23.734984
127 2021-09-27  00:00:00  43160.90  44350.00  42098.00  42147.35    39776.843830  23.925323
128 2021-09-28  00:00:00  42147.35  42787.38  40888.00  41026.54    43372.262400  24.312088
129 2021-09-29  00:00:00  41025.01  42590.00  40753.88  41524.28    33511.534870  24.702028
130 2021-09-30  00:00:00  41524.29  44141.37  41410.17  43824.10    46381.227810  24.581907
131 2021-01-10  00:00:00  43820.01  48495.00  43283.03  48141.61    66244.874920  23.367632
132 2021-02-10  00:00:00  48141.60  48336.59  47430.18  47634.90    30508.981310  22.214071
133 2021-03-10  00:00:00  47634.89  49228.08  47088.00  48200.01    30825.056010  21.285226
134 2021-04-10  00:00:00  48200.01  49536.12  46891.00  49224.94    46796.493720  20.470586
135 2021-05-10  00:00:00  49224.93  51886.30  49022.40  51471.99    52125.667930  20.178783
136 2021-06-10  00:00:00  51471.99  55750.00  50382.41  55315.00    79877.545181  20.539207
137 2021-07-10  00:00:00  55315.00  55332.31  53357.00  53785.22    54917.377660  20.881611
138 2021-08-10  00:00:00  53785.22  56100.00  53617.61  53951.43    46160.257850  21.322501
139 2021-09-10  00:00:00  53955.67  55489.00  53661.67  54949.72    55177.080130  21.741347
140 2021-10-10  00:00:00  54949.72  56561.31  54080.00  54659.00    89237.836128  22.304343
141 2021-11-10  00:00:00  54659.01  57839.04  54415.06  57471.35    52933.165751  23.025557
142 2021-12-10  00:00:00  57471.35  57680.00  53879.00  55996.93    53471.285500  23.546775
143 2021-10-13  00:00:00  55996.91  57777.00  54167.19  57367.00    55808.444920  24.057061
144 2021-10-14  00:00:00  57370.83  58532.54  56818.05  57347.94    43053.336781  24.660876
145 2021-10-15  00:00:00  57347.94  62933.00  56850.00  61672.42    82512.908022  25.811065
146 2021-10-16  00:00:00  61672.42  62378.42  60150.00  60875.57    35467.880960  26.903744
147 2021-10-17  00:00:00  60875.57  61718.39  58963.00  61528.33    39099.241240  27.563757
148 2021-10-18  00:00:00  61528.32  62695.78  59844.45  62009.84    51798.448440  28.318027
149 2021-10-19  00:00:00  62005.60  64486.00  61322.22  64280.59    53628.107744  29.251726
150 2021-10-20  00:00:00  64280.59  67000.00  63481.40  66001.41    51428.934856  30.405550
151 2021-10-21  00:00:00  66001.40  66639.74  62000.00  62193.15    68538.645370  31.054053
152 2021-10-22  00:00:00  62193.15  63732.39  60000.00  60688.22    52119.358860  31.117531
153 2021-10-23  00:00:00  60688.23  61747.64  59562.15  61286.75    27626.936780  31.062358
154 2021-10-24  00:00:00  61286.75  61500.00  59510.63  60852.22    31226.576760  30.995921
155 2021-10-25  00:00:00  60852.22  63710.63  60650.00  63078.78    36853.838060  31.244720
156 2021-10-26  00:00:00  63078.78  63293.48  59817.55  60328.81    40217.500830  31.249961
157 2021-10-27  00:00:00  60328.81  61496.00  58000.00  58413.44    62124.490160  30.779004
158 2021-10-28  00:00:00  58413.44  62499.00  57820.00  60575.89    61056.353010  30.489479
159 2021-10-29  00:00:00  60575.90  62980.00  60174.81  62253.71    43973.904140  30.289382
160 2021-10-30  00:00:00  62253.70  62359.25  60673.00  61859.19    31478.125660  30.099291
161 2021-10-31  00:00:00  61859.19  62405.30  59945.36  61299.80    39267.637940  29.713720
162 2021-01-11  00:00:00  61299.81  62437.74  59405.00  60911.11    44687.666720  29.196216
163 2021-02-11  00:00:00  60911.12  64270.00  60624.68  63219.99    46368.284100  29.031364
164 2021-03-11  00:00:00  63220.57  63500.00  60382.76  62896.48    43336.090490  28.804634
165 2021-04-11  00:00:00  62896.49  63086.31  60677.01  61395.01    35930.933140  28.589242
166 2021-05-11  00:00:00  61395.01  62595.72  60721.00  60937.12    31604.487490  28.384619
167 2021-06-11  00:00:00  60940.18  61560.49  60050.00  61470.61    25590.574080  27.973716
168 2021-07-11  00:00:00  61470.62  63286.35  61322.78  63273.59    25515.688300  27.926901
169 2021-08-11  00:00:00  63273.58  67789.00  63273.58  67525.83    54442.094554  28.579845
170 2021-09-11  00:00:00  67525.82  68524.25  66222.40  66947.66    44661.378068  29.294016
171 2021-10-11  00:00:00  66947.67  69000.00  62822.90  64882.43    65171.504046  29.014734
172 2021-11-11  00:00:00  64882.42  65600.07  64100.00  64774.26    37237.980580  28.749416
173 2021-12-11  00:00:00  64774.25  65450.70  62278.00  64122.23    44490.108160  28.041179
174 2021-11-13  00:00:00  64122.22  65000.00  63360.22  64380.00    22504.973830  27.368353
175 2021-11-14  00:00:00  64380.01  65550.51  63576.27  65519.10    25705.073470  26.832078
176 2021-11-15  00:00:00  65519.11  66401.82  63400.00  63606.74    37829.371240  26.479925
177 2021-11-16  00:00:00  63606.73  63617.31  58574.07  60058.87    77455.156090  25.267463
178 2021-11-17  00:00:00  60058.87  60840.23  58373.00  60344.87    46289.384910  24.154719
179 2021-11-18  00:00:00  60344.86  60976.00  56474.26  56891.62    62146.999310  23.454728
180 2021-11-19  00:00:00  56891.62  58320.00  55600.00  58052.24    50715.887260  22.944550
181 2021-11-20  00:00:00  58057.10  59845.00  57353.00  59707.51    33811.590100  22.122892
182 2021-11-21  00:00:00  59707.52  60029.76  58486.65  58622.02    31902.227850  21.302202
183 2021-11-22  00:00:00  58617.70  59444.00  55610.00  56247.18    51724.320470  21.040602
184 2021-11-23  00:00:00  56243.83  58009.99  55317.00  57541.27    49917.850170  20.840946
185 2021-11-24  00:00:00  57541.26  57735.00  55837.00  57138.29    39612.049640  20.651273
186 2021-11-25  00:00:00  57138.29  59398.90  57000.00  58960.36    42153.515220  20.071560
187 2021-11-26  00:00:00  58960.37  59150.00  53500.00  53726.53    65927.870660  20.117912
188 2021-11-27  00:00:00  53723.72  55280.00  53610.00  54721.03    29716.999570  20.161946
189 2021-11-28  00:00:00  54716.47  57445.05  53256.64  57274.88    36163.713700  19.704241
190 2021-11-29  00:00:00  57274.89  58865.97  56666.67  57776.25    40125.280090  18.969898
191 2021-11-30  00:00:00  57776.25  59176.99  55875.55  56950.56    49161.051940  18.417868
192 2021-01-12  00:00:00  56950.56  59053.55  56458.01  57184.07    44956.636560  17.893439
193 2021-02-12  00:00:00  57184.07  57375.47  55777.77  56480.34    37574.059760  17.525876
194 2021-03-12  00:00:00  56484.26  57600.00  51680.00  53601.05    58927.690270  17.858850
195 2021-04-12  00:00:00  53601.05  53859.10  42000.30  49152.47   114203.373748  19.217441
196 2021-05-12  00:00:00  49152.46  49699.05  47727.21  49396.33    45580.820120  20.508102
197 2021-06-12  00:00:00  49396.32  50891.11  47100.00  50441.92    58571.215750  21.472003
198 2021-07-12  00:00:00  50441.91  51936.33  50039.74  50588.95    38253.468770  22.161968
199 2021-08-12  00:00:00  50588.95  51200.00  48600.00  50471.19    38425.924660  22.962218
200 2021-09-12  00:00:00  50471.19  50797.76  47320.00  47545.59    37692.686650  23.846688
201 2021-10-12  00:00:00  47535.90  50125.00  46852.00  47140.54    44233.573910  24.732127
202 2021-11-12  00:00:00  47140.54  49485.71  46751.00  49389.99    28889.193580  25.583369
203 2021-12-12  00:00:00  49389.99  50777.00  48638.00  50053.90    26017.934210  26.077754
204 2021-12-13  00:00:00  50053.90  50189.97  45672.75  46702.75    50869.520930  26.859770
205 2021-12-14  00:00:00  46702.76  48700.41  46290.00  48343.28    39955.984450  27.602685
206 2021-12-15  00:00:00  48336.95  49500.00  46547.00  48864.98    51629.181000  28.109255
207 2021-12-16  00:00:00  48864.98  49436.43  47511.00  47632.38    31949.867390  28.590496
208 2021-12-17  00:00:00  47632.38  47995.96  45456.00  46131.20    43104.488700  29.278437
209 2021-12-18  00:00:00  46133.83  47392.37  45500.00  46834.48    25020.052710  29.931981
210 2021-12-19  00:00:00  46834.47  48300.01  46406.91  46681.23    29305.706650  30.303705
211 2021-12-20  00:00:00  46681.24  47537.57  45558.85  46914.16    35848.506090  30.761072
212 2021-12-21  00:00:00  46914.17  49328.96  46630.00  48889.88    37713.929240  30.715132
213 2021-12-22  00:00:00  48887.59  49576.13  48421.87  48588.16    27004.202200  30.607162
214 2021-12-23  00:00:00  48588.17  51375.00  47920.42  50838.81    35192.540460  30.051098
215 2021-12-24  00:00:00  50838.82  51810.00  50384.43  50820.00    31661.949460  29.417439
```

When run below code is well. But I need date in `x` axis

```
test['avg'].plot(legend=True,figsize=(12,5))
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('ADX')
plt.ylabel('date')
plt.title('ADX indicator')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Correct plot:

[image]

But when I chose `date` for `x` axis, I take a bad plot. Code is below:

```
 df.set_index('date',drop=True, inplace=True)
```

[Modified data](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1LDWEyUqOJ_qzkleVbO7OBweW_71XqDOH)

```
test['avg'].plot(legend=True,figsize=(12,5))
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('ADX')
plt.ylabel('date')
plt.title('ADX indicator')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Bad plot:

[image]
and also why I take NaN value for ADX in TA-lib
Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: link work for me(data from google drive and image uplode on stackoverflow).thank for your comment

Comment: Both links for data are not working. If they are text files, just paste their contents in the body of the question.

Comment: i solve problem and you can download data

Comment: Tip: Whenever you experience problems, have a look at the raw data first. Your input data are scrambled. Some of the dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format, others in YYYY-DD-MM format. No parser can guess which date is in which format. Make sure to have a consistent date format when downloading these data wherever you get them from.

Comment: I take data from binance with GetHistoricalData      @Mr. T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does appear to be the problem of the source file. The column names are not tab separated. Once this is fixed, the plotting works fine.

The NaN issue is also the source file; the average was not calculated for the first several rows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test = pd.read_csv(r"modified_data.dat", sep='\t')

test.set_index('date')

date = test['date']
avg = test['avg']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
ax.plot(date, avg)
ax.tick_params(rotation=30, width = 2)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(date)+1, 5))
ax.set_xticks
```

Output looks like this: [image]

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: You are very welcome! If it works for you, can you accept it? Thanks :)